# JOGL OpenGL in Eclipse throwing NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, jogl

I'm want to learn OpenGL using Java.  I have no experience using OpenGL but I am comfortable with Java.

The plan is to use JOGL in Eclipse Indigo. To get started a simple hello world application was written from [Schabby's Blog](http://schabby.de/jogl-example-hello-world/). The source for my application is the same.

I follow all steps and reference the *gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar, gluegen-rt.jar, jogl-all.jar and jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar* libraries. The application is configured to run in JRE6 x64.

When I run the application the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jogamp.common.awt.AWTEDTExecutor.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;ZZLjava/lang/Runnable;)Z
```

Other answers suggests that the problem is with the main method, however I do not see any problems with it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
       \\Implementation
}
```

What else can I try to solve this problem?

**EDIT:** It seems the exception is thrown every time something needs to be drawn.

If I comment this line `frame.setSize( frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize() );` a default frame with minimum width and height is shown but as soon as I re-size the same exception is thrown.

Comment: @11684 is not fair.  I have a Desktop app with almost 1M downloads using JOGL.  JOGL's not perfect, but I have surveyed open source libraries and it's the best I can find.  Be aware that MacOS Lion and ML changed the video system heavily and Oracle fiddled with the rendering pipeline in JRE7, so the JOGL implementers have been faced with enormous version splitting beyond their control. If you field a Mac app where you have no client config control, there will be problems.  The other issue is that OpenGL drivers are generally more buggy in Windows because Direct3D/X is a bigger market.

Comment: @Gene I couldn't post the following comment due to SO going in read only mode:

Comment: To what? JOGL? No. But I'm sorry, I didn't want to discourage you from using JOGL, that I think it was a disaster because I couldn't get it to work doesn't mean you can't! It might be an issue with my computers settings or something, but probably it's just me who messed it up. @blaffie

Comment: Hi. Shabby made some really confusing and plain wrong tutorials about JOGL, I asked him to fix them, I contacted him publicly on Youtube and by email, please don't use his tutorials. Rather put the JARs containing the native libraries into the same directory than jogl-all.jar, even the JARs that you consider useless, so that it will work even your JVM looks for the 32-bits natives whereas you expected it to pick the 64-bits natives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the top level exception thrown when the native libraries can't be loaded.  See [the documentation on local installation](http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/userguide/#localinstallation) and follow carefully.

First make sure that the JRE Eclipse is using is actually 64-bit. Your behavior is consistent with trying to load 64-bit DLLs in a 32-bit JRE.

Note also the blog is somewhat dated.  For example `jogl.all.jar` is now `jogl-all.jar`.   Make sure your jar references are to the correct files.   You might get better results with [this set of instructions, which is based on the current release](http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd470/Winter_13/JOGL2%20Installation-rc11.pdf).

The natives jar is expanded at run time.  The directory where this jar is stored must be writeable for this mechanism to work.  I usually go through the more detailed procedure of using the expanded DLL/jnilib/so files and setting java.library.path to eliminate all doubt.